# ionic globalization with react and web

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to get the current language of the user's browser.

I installed @ionic-native/globalization.

But I get this error :

```
uncaught exception: cordova_not_available
```

I call getPreferredLanguage

```
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';

const foo = await Globalization.getPreferredLanguage();
```

I'm lauching the app throught :

```
npx cap serve
```

Comment: Capacitor doesn't support Cordova plugins on web platform

Answer (score 1):

As @jcesarmobile says, Capacitor doesn't support Cordova plugins on web plateform.

Then I have change my code to this :

```
const GetLocale = async (): Promise<string> => {
    if (isPlatform('cordova') || isPlatform('capacitor')) {
        return await (await Globalization.getPreferredLanguage()).value;
    } else {
        return navigator.language; // web. Not sur that the if is complete
    }
}
```

Not sure if that is the perfect way, but it's seems to work for me.